# How much payload can a space elevator support?

Tags: physics, space, space-elevators

I'm working on a project involving an interstellar society, and I'm looking to incorporate as much actual science and economics into the project itself since I'm a stickler for numbers and logistics. However, because I'm a stickler for numbers and logistics, I've found myself in a bit of a quandary as I've inevitably encountered the subject of space elevators as an efficient means of moving goods and people into and out of orbit. The problem I've encountered specifically is what payload levels could be moved into orbit along a space elevator, and the amount of power that would be required to sustain such an activity.

My question is this:

- How do I determine how much payload a space elevator can lift where fusion power is readily available?
- How do I determine what the most reasonable ascent speed is for the space elevator?

As I've mentioned, as much as I love science and technology, it's not a passion that I've pursued outside of creative hobbies such as worldbuilding. If you could break down the details in a somewhat comprehensible manner, I'd be ever so grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be just one question and ask the second one separately, or ask bring the text in line with the title ("how much payload") which might involve other factors than power consumption/delivery.

Comment: How realistic is the idea of a space elevator in the first place?

Comment: Space elevator potential payload is limited by the strength of the tether. It's feasibility depends on strength to weight ratio of the material that is used for the tether, and the payload amount is determined by how much more weight we can safely add to it.

Comment: @Alexander That would explain a lot and why I couldn't find a solid number on what payload amounts could be supported. Thank you.

Comment: The payload and the ascent speed *are* directly related to one another and should be considered together, since the acceleration increases the weight.  It's a pity that the close voters, whose work here is so much more important than that of those who ask or answer questions, haven't had a chance to think of that.  It's probably best revise the question and resubmit it - on physicsforums.com.

Comment: I check a number of proposal papers a while back and the average payload in these papers was 15 tons per week. That convinced me that space elevators are severely overhyped and that skyhooks, laser launch, launchloops and ultimately orbital rings are vastly superior systems. All of those can actually be built with current materials, although high temperature superconductors would be helpful for the latter two.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight the interesting thing about a space elevator is that it can be effectively used as its own scaffolding for expanding it into a _bigger_ space elevator. An initial load of 15 tonnes a week gets expanded to 100-1000 tonnes a week after a few years as the cable is widened. Of the things you listed, I'd say that launchloops are barely plausible, orbital rings are little simpler than space elevators and skyhooks seem like they'll be impractical for a very long time. Laser launch is the only realistic short/medium term option, IMHO.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yea, the bootstrapping argument. But that counts for most of the other options as well and they'll often get you better returns on investment. Low atmosphere skyhooks are difficult, but ones in higher eccentric orbits are great for interplanetary travel. And even the low orbit version is quite useful. Orbital rings provide vastly more utility than space elevators though. I guess it depends on how active support technology pans out. If it works, the space elevator pales in comparison to the space fountain.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight yeah, orbital rings would be basically better than all the rest, but they're also _waaaaay_ more complex than even space elevators. I'm not entirely convinced of the practicality of skyhooks either, but I'd find it harder justifying my stance against those. FWIW, my gonzo megastructure favorite is the startram, I'd like to think it is easier than all the rest by a couple of orders of magnitude, and no less useful.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I've never heard of orbital rings or at least never paid much attention to them. If they are more efficient in lifting payloads into orbit, I'll give it a look and see how that goes. As for the main issue of space elevators, you're saying that the cable can be expanded to increase the payload amount? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Vivaporius a lifter could take a long roll of thing carbon nanotube tape and a tub of epoxy with them, and glue it on as they ascend. Repeat weekly for a few years until your elevator is sufficiently science-fictional. Orbital rings are _awesome_ for many reasons, but they involve making a powered, moving structure that's tens of thousands of kilometres in size. They're harder to make than space elevators, but if you could make a launch loops, then there's a gradual path to making orbital rings. I don't think launch loops are very practical, however.

Comment: @StarfishPrime That's pretty awesome come to think about it. Though the more I take those details into account, the more I feel it veers off into another series of questions beyond the one that I posted here. You'll likely hear from me again on the orbital ring in the near future as I explore that avenue for my project. That and the launch loops of course. It's always something else...

Comment: @Vivaporius here's some introductory reading for you, if you've not already come across the paper: https://space.nss.org/wp-content/uploads/Orbital-Rings.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum load of the elevator doesn't depend on your power technology, but your material technology.

- the maximum load of a lifter on your space elevator is determined by the thickness of the lower end of the cable.
- the thickness of the lower end of the cable will be kept as low as possible to reduce the weight of the entire elevator, and hence the difficulty in building the thing in the first place.
- the thicker the bottom end of the cable, the fatter the middle of the cable, and the heavier and more complex to make the whole elevator is

Really, anything from 20 tonnes or a thousands tonnes or more is fine... handwave in whatever you want to suit your story needs. Lighter loads for lower tech levels, partially constructed elevators with only a thin cable that's still being expanded, higher gravity worlds, etc.

The speed of your elevator is is limited partially by how it is attached to the cable, and partially by how it gets power. Elevators are more efficient than rockets, but there's still a lot of energy required to lift a load up to the geosynchronous point.

[Specific orbital energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy) is the number to care about here. The important parameters are $R$ the radius of the planet you are lifting from, $a$ the  [radius of a geostationary orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_orbit), $M$ the mass of the planet and $G$ the [gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant). $\mu$ is the [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter), $GM$. The amount of energy you have to expend to raise the lifter is defined as $$\epsilon_a = -{\mu \over 2a} + {\mu \over R }$$

For Earth, you'll have an $\epsilon_a$ of ~57.77MJ/kg. A hundred tonne lifter would need ~5.777TJ. If your lifter managed an average speed of 600km/h, you'd make the trip from the surface to orbit in a little under 60 hours, and need a steady power supply of about 27 megawatts sustained for the whole journey.

If fusion power is effective, compact and safe, you could fit a mini reactor to the lifter. Given the weight requirements, this seems unlikely unless you have a really substantial cable and a very large lifter of a few thousand tonnes or more. If fusion reactors are big and heavy and awkward (which is likely), you might keep them on the ground (or in orbit) and use laser or microwave beamed power to drive the lifters motors.

If you wanted a faster trip, you might be able to handwave one in given suitable power supplies, though cable friction is going to be a problem. Some kind of fancy superconducting magnetically levitated linear motor might work, but all that extra weight on the cable has to be held up by something...

Please also remember that you get *one* lifter per cable. if you want multiple lifters, you'll have difficulty fitting them past each other, even if the cable was very large indeed. Here's a reasonable artist's impression of a lifter. See how it encompasses the cable, and is quite broad in order to accomodate beamed power collection arrays:

[image: artist's impression of a beamed power lifter with two large circular collection arrays on either side of the cable]

(image credit [Liftport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SpaceElevatorInClouds.jpg))

---

I'll spare you the gory details of elevator cable width, but if anyone *really* wants me to walk you through it and doesn't fancy reading eg. [The physics of the space elevator](https://users.wpi.edu/%7Eparavind/Publications/PKASpace%20Elevators.pdf) to work it out themselves, do ask.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This is actually very comprehensive and touches on all of the questions I had regarding space elevators. I have no issue reading up on the gory bits if you have them to share. Thank you again.